# How to not make the program restart after a value error?

Tags: python, pycharm

So I recently started coding and just learned about 'try' and 'except' for 'ValueError'. I made this calculator but it restarts if you don't input an int on the 'second' input. How do I make it ask for pnly the 'second' variable instead of asking for the first one again?

```
while True:
    try:
        first = int(input("First: "))
        second = int(input("Second: "))
        sum = first + second
        print(f"Sum: {sum}")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("I didn't understand that")
```

I tried this but it just asked for the second variable then restarted the program

```
while True:
    try:
        first = int(input("First: "))
        second = int(input("Second: "))
        sum = first + second
        print(f"Sum: {sum}")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("I didn't understand that")
        int(input("Second: "))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate while with try/except blocks for the two prompts. And since you are doing the same thing multiple times, put the common part in a function

```
def get_input(prompt, cast_to=int):
    while True:
        try:
            return cast_to(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("I didn't understand that")

first = get_input("First: ")
second = get_input("Second: ")
sum = first + second
print(f"Sum {sum}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate function for inputting the number:

```py
def GetNumberInput(text: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(text))
        except ValueError:
            print("I didn't understand that")
        

first = GetNumberInput("First: ")
second = GetNumberInput("Second: ")
sum = first + second
print(f"Sum: {sum}")
```

Output:

```
First: 123
Second: aaa
I didn't understand that
Second: 456
Sum: 579
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem you are facing is because as you exit the `try-except` block, the loop reiterates which leads to the first input again. You can avoid this behavior by taking the loop in a separate function, like so:

```py
def take_input(text):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(text))
        except ValueError:
            print("I didn't understand that")
```

You can then call this function whenever you require the input like, `num = take_input("Input: ")`. The complete implementation of your calculator would look like this:

```py
def take_input(text):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(text))
        except ValueError:
            print("I didn't understand that")

first = GetNumberInput("First: ")
second = GetNumberInput("Second: ")
sum = first + second
print(f"Sum: {sum}")
```

Now the loop only runs when the `return` value is hit, else you go through another iteration of the loop, and so on and so forth. Hope you understand the logic behind this!